# Find subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{19})$ with index 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Find subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{19})$ with index 3

My try:

I thought about looking at $\det:GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{19}) \to\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ and finding a subgroup of index 3 of $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$.

I know that $[\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*:H]=[GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_{19}):\det^{-1}(H)]$ given that $H$ is a normal subgroup.

So, I need to find a normal $H<\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$  such that $[\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*:H] = 3$

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well known fact, that for a prime $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. In your case it is $\langle 2 \rangle_{18}$. Thus, the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^*$ that you need, is generated by $2^3 = 8$. 
And thus, the subgroup, you were initially looking for is $\{A \in GL(n, 19)| \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, det(A) = 8^n \}$

Comment: Why $\langle 7 \rangle$ is of index 3 though?

Comment: That subgroup has index $6$, not $3$. You want the subgroup generated by $2^3 = 8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How did you know to pick 8? Do you just calculate order of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ or is there a more clever way?

Comment: I said in my comment, I picked $8$ as $2^3$, and $2$ generates the group (i.e. it has order $18$).